# How to make a simple contact form using Django?

Tags: python, html, django, windows

I am new to Django 1.9 and I am currently coding a website. I am trying to make a contact form to go on the contact page. I have used the following code - which is in the a file called email.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

I've defined it in the view.py file:

```
from .forms import PostForm, ContactForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['nmam.ltd@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, "blog/email.html", {'form': form})

def thanks(request):
    return HttpResponse('Thank you for your message.')

.....
```

As well as in the forms.py file:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Also, in the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^general.html/$', views.general, name='general'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/$', views.dcmain, name='dcmain'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/big_data.html/$', views.big_data, name='big_data'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/Data_Architecture.html/$', views.Data_Architecture, name='Data_Architecture'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/BI_MI.html/$', views.BI_MI, name='BI_MI'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/Master_Data.html/$', views.Master_Data, name='Master_Data'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/Data_Q.html/$', views.Data_Q, name='Data_Q'),
    url(r'^dcmain.html/Project_M.html/$', views.Project_M, name='Project_M'),
    url(r'^email.html/$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
 ]
```

When I link the email.html file to the main page and click on the link and it just shows the home page even though the url says I am on the email.html page (shown below):

[image: picture]

I am totally new to programming in Django. I have tried researching it however, I can't find a solution. Please can someone help me.

Comment: I feel like the url you omitted is the problem, can you show all of them?

Comment: Also, don't make your url as `email.html`, that's for the template not for url.

Comment: <a href="email.html">Contact</a> - thats the url I have used to connect the main page to the email.html file. And what url do i use then?

Comment: `urlpatterns` is the url I'm talking about.

Comment: I've edited it above to show you all url patterns

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are most likely the problem. You can read more on Django URLs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Note, as the Django docs mention, the first URL pattern which matches the requested URL will be used. As a basic rule of thumb, I recommend putting your more specific URL patterns before your blank url patterns. For instance:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^email.html/$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='some_name'),
]
```

If this urls.py file is being included from a project urls.py file, you'll want these urls to be included before your root url pattern.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog'),
    url(r'', views.site_home, name='site_home'),
]
```

Which would then make your url to this page

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:email' %}">Email</a>
```

Which would render as

```
<a href="yoursite.com/blog/email.html">Email</a>
```

Comment: What are the two urls referring two which you have added?

Comment: They're an example of what your root project urls.py file might look like, if it's including urls from a django app urls.py file. The point I was trying to make is that your matching url patterns must come BEFORE a different url pattern that might accidentally match the requested url. Also, depending on your url patterns & structure, you might need to try hitting "blog/email.html" instead of "email.html"

Comment: do I have to put anything in the models.py for the contact form

Comment: No, you don't HAVE to (not based on your example at least, because you're only using the submitted data to send an email). That being said, it can be a nice user feature to store form submissions in a database for later viewing/retrieval